# Skype for business Core/Plugin Java API

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I need to develop one feature in my tool like for some operation is success then tool needs to ping the person in the skype and give initimation about the result.

My tool is developed by eclipse plugin so please let me know is there any Java API which I can use to send a message through Skype for Business 2015.

Currently i have used one blog(https://o7planning.org/en/10153/skype-java-api-tutorial) but i was getting com.skype.NotAttachedException always. And i have seen that it's personal skype not a business one.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

UCWA is a good solution for your case.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/sendmessage_ref

you can send a message to a user using this API. and it is language independent which means you can use JAVA from your project.